# Facebook App in Profile Tab: problems getting the user session

Tags: facebook, authentication, fbjs

I'm working in a mini-app, which will have 3 pages, and i want all the interaction to happen inside a profile-tab.So, using javascript, i want to show/hide a few divs, which i'll populate using the FBJS ajax object.

My problem is, i'm not getting the user session in the ajax calls.As documentation is extremely confusing, i've ended up not knowing if this is possible at all.Any ideas?

Comment: Ok..solved..To anybody who finds this: DONT use the new PHP SDK..Use the old one..So it's possible to call set_user with the params the ajax sends.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's id if you require login from your ajax request on a profile tab.  For instance:

```
var ajax = new Ajax();
ajax.responseType = Ajax.RAW;
ajax.ondone = function(data) {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
}
ajax.onerror = function(data) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(data);
}
ajax.requireLogin = true;
ajax.post('http://DOMAIN/add_story', {story: story});
```

The requireLogin = true part will cause an authorization window to popup.  If they agree, you can get the user ID in your AJAX handler using the PHP SDK, like:

```
$facebook->getUser();
```